Only add All-Day OOO events in Google App Script Vacation Calendar
I am trying to use the vacation calendar app script but I only want to include all-day events, regardless of whether people are using a default event or an OOO event. There is a similar question here: Ignore not All-Day events in the Google App Script Vacation Calendar but this answer only works for default events and all OOO-type events are being filtered out
This type of event always returns that it is not all day, even when it is:

The Event class returned by Calendar.Events.list() does not appear to contain this information, but per the other thread I altered to retrieve a CalendarEvent object and it works correctly if the calendar event is a default event type. However, if the event is an outOfOffice event then everything returns as not all day, even when it is, which means none of my OOO events get added. Does anyone know how to get it to correctly read the OOO events for all-day vs timed?
The relevant code is this shouldImportEvent function:
function shouldImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Only import events that are all day
  let calEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(user.getEmail()).getEventById(event.id)
  if (!calEvent.isAllDayEvent()) {
    // all outOfOffice events are returning here
    return false; 
  }

  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}


Why not use !calEvent.isAllDayEvent() && calEvent.getEventType() !== "outOfOffice"?

On your case I would suggest taking advantage of working with Start Time and End time of event instead of Utilizing AllDayEvent() for everything. Feel free to provide more information about your goal. What  should be marked events? What are the requirements for this this way the community can provide your a more specific answer to your issue.

I did end up using the start and end times and excluding anything with a duration of less than 7 hours, whichi s working fine.

@BeRT2me apologies if my goal was not clear but I wanted to include ONLY all-day events of both default and ooo event types; the ooo events are always returning as not all day regardless of whether they were or not, so there was no way to use the isAllDayEvent successfully

Not as clean as I was hoping for but I ended up using the start and end times and checking the duration instead, which works just fine:
// Only import events that are all day
let calEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(user.getEmail()).getEventById(event.id);
let durationHours = (calEvent.getEndTime() - calEvent.getStartTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60; 

if (durationHours < 7) {
  return false;
}

